# Can Rails ActiveRecord #save method be used to update an existing record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Can the `#save` method be used to update a record?

I know that I can *create* a new record using save, like this:

```
person = Person.new 
person.save # rails will insert the new record into the database.
```

However, if I find an existing record first, modify the model, and then save it, is this the same result as performing a update?

```
person = Person.find(:first, :condition => "id = 1") 
person.name = "my_new_name" 
person.save # is this save performing a update or insert?
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes. An ActiveRecord object in Rails retains its identity in the ID parameter. If the ID is set, Rails will know to update the record in the database with that ID.

`save` is, in fact, the primary way to create, update, or in any way save an object to the database. Other methods like `update_attributes` are just sugar that use `save` at their core.

Comment: This is not true.. person = Person.new  person.id = 23  person.save fails.. It is no the id that tells it that it's new.

Comment: does save have to be preformed? can it just be person.name = 'new name'?

Comment: It doesn't work. Save does both updates an existing record and creates a new one anyway.

Answer (score 4):

this is an update.

[save(perform_validation = true)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002329)

```
  # File vendor/rails/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb, line 2533
2533:       def save
2534:         create_or_update
2535:       end
```

Comment: Funny how three years later that method isn’t in base.rb anymore…